# Taylor series with remainder term for $\ln(1+x)$ about 1 with error terms less than $2^{-10}$

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I was working on this problem and I think I was able to get the correct Taylor series representation but I'm struggling with the number of error terms. I need an inequality that gives the number of terms that must be taken in order to yield ln(4)with error terms less than $2^{-10}$. For the series I got $$f(x) = \ln(2) + \frac{x-1}{2} + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{-1^{n+1}(n-1)!}{2^n}(x-1)^n.$$ For the remainder inequality I'm getting $\frac{3^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} < \frac{1}{2^{-10}}$ but when plugging this into a calculator it states that $n < -1$ which clearly doesn't make sense. Can someone help with the error term ?

Comment: How did you "plug into a calculator"?

Comment: @Semiclassical I plugged that inequality into wolfram alpha online in order to find the values for n and it stated n < -1

Comment: Are you referring to a usage like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+3%5E%28n%2B1%29%2F%28n%2B1%29%21+%3C+2%5E%28-10%29+for+n)? If you keep clicking "More solutions" it'll show more and more. (Actually, it's simpler to ask for which $n$ the inequality is reversed.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Oh thank you i didnt notice that, although unfortunately I still think I'm messing up the remainder term because I think the answer is much greater than that. I think it is suppose to be n >  2^10 - 1

Comment: Do you have a statement of the original problem? Also, your expression for the Taylor series seems dubious: What enters into the Taylor series as the $n$th coefficient is $f^{(n)}(1)/n!$, not just the derivative.

Comment: Please don't delete questions when someone has gone to the effort of answering.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your formula for the infinite series is certainly wrong, ’cause as written it’s nowhere convergent. Look again. But I’d do the thing entirely differently.

Using $\log(1+x)=-\sum_1^\infty(-x)^n/n$ and $\log(1-x)=-\sum_1^\infty x^n/n$, you get
$$
\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=2\left(x+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5+\cdots\right)\,.
$$
Now of course this isn’t an alternating series, which makes it a little harder to estimate the error when cutting off at a finite number of terms; but since $x=\frac35$ will give you the logarithm of $4$, it looks to me as if you’d only need to go to about $x^{15}/15$, thus eight terms. I leave the details to you.